# How to exit automatically at end of file on vim?

Tags: vim, less-unix

I tried `vim/less.sh` as pager with syntax highlighting, but there is a little issue:
when displaying small file, vim uses 'full screen' and waits for a command from user.

Can I let vim to act like a `less --quit-at-eof`?

In other words, is there a way to automatically quit vim if displayed file is several lines length?

I found one solution with a shell script: count file lines by `wc -l`, then get terminal height, if size is small - use custom vim config file, where custom config file ending with `:quit` string.

However, this solution looks terrible and leave extra lines with `~` after end of small file, so I'm looking for better way to do this.

Comment: `In other words, is there a way to automatically quit vim if displayed file is several lines length?` In another words, if your file has *several* lines length, vim shouldn't open/display it at all?

Comment: No, on my system (FreeBSD 8.2) is doesn't switch to alternate terminal page, so content is still displayed after exit.

Answer (score 2):

Vim switches to the *alternate terminal page*, so when you exit it, its contents are gone. Even if you turn that off:

```
$ vim --cmd 'set t_ti= t_te='
```

UI stuff like the `~`, *ruler* and *statusline* would remain, too. Therefore, the solution you've found looks like a reasonable workaround. Either use that or (better) get used to quitting the Vim pager.